# blank desktop after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Oracle virtual box

Tags: 14.04

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my oracle virtualbox, after installation, it brings forth a blank desktop without any programs or applications on it. It will display "Guest Operating system" and ask for password. After typing in the password, it still shows blank desktop.

Also, I tried installing "Virtualbox additional disk image", but to no avail.

Please, what do I do to resolve these issues?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am a several years long user of VirtualBox and have noticed this issue with the latest version of Kubuntu (15.04) and the latest version of VirtualBox (4.3.28). I can install Kubuntu just fine on the virtual machine, and get into the desktop, but once I run updates I begin getting the blank screen after login.

I'm beginning to believe it is an issue with the latest Linux Kernel, since that is a part of the update package. Either the kernel is incompatible with VirtualBox, or something in Kubuntu.