# Ubuntu 18.04 on oracle virtual box 6

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I manage to install ubuntu 18.04 on oracle vm 6, but as soon as i install the new updates it dosen't work anymore - i get only the background of ubuntu login screen but without the login's input.

I repeated the installation few times and the problem occurs just if i install the updates.

The problem repeat with both linux and windows OS as host.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626243/blank-desktop-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-oracle-virtual-box) SO question that didn't help me... Didn't found anything productive on the web either..

Is this a knows issue? How it can be fixed?

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions?

Comment: Now i did. After installing the updates it doesn't show anything - just a blank black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i manage to solve the problem by formatting entirely the computer (host), installed virtual-box, installed ubuntu, installed the guest addition, and finally updated the system.

Didn't work without formatting. 
Didn't work with different order.
Believe me i tried...

Thank you @GabrielaGarcia for you willing to help.